# Remove multiple items in Eloquent Lists

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I know that when I exceute the code below, the supplier with `id 1` will not be included in the lists.

`Supplier::where('id', '!=', 1)->lists('supplier_name', 'id');`

So my question is if I have an array of ids to pass inside the variable. How can I use to exclude multiple ids on the lists?

plain and simple I have tried `Supplier::where('id', '!=', [1,2])->lists('supplier_name', 'id');` it seems this not the proper way to do it.

Comment: `whereNotIn` method have look. Example: `Supplier::whereNotIn('id', array(1,3,4,5,6))->lists('supplier_name');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
$listOfIds = array(1, 2);
Supplier::whereNotIn('id', $listOfIds)->lists('supplier_name', 'id');
```

Note the whereNotIn which takes in the name and then an array of the values.

The docs only mention it once as far as I can see about a quarter of the way down on this page.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries